# Disable TapGestureRecognizer for a specific image

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have 4 image over a view. 3 of them are assigned with TapGestureRecognizer & another 1 is `PanGestureRecognizer`. Now i want to disable the `TapGestureRecognizer` for only 1 specific image after a certain time. For this purpose i did:

```
[cat setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

But it don't disable the `TapGestureRecognizer`. Then also did this:

```
[cat setHidden:YES];
```

None of them are working. Here cat is the image i want to disable the `TapGestureRecognizer` for. What is the solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: show me how you assign the tap on imageviews

Comment: just disable user interaction for particular imageview.
using `[imgView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]`

Comment: Please show us how you add the gesture over UIImageView.And are you sure if you add UIImageView in xib then set the IBOutLet.

Comment: @iPhoneDev Yes, i am.

Comment: Hi Leo, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Set recognizer's delegate and implement this method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if (gestureRecognizer == tapRecognizerToDisable && 
    CGRectContainsPoint(_imageToDisable.bounds, [touch locationInView:_imageToDisable]))
        return NO;
    else
        return YES;
}
```

This will work disregarding to which view tapRecognizerToDisable is added.